# Can R cause a file to be opened by another program?

Tags: r, externalinterface

This is a bit of a strange question, but I thought people here might be interested.

Is it possible to have R cause a file to be opened in another program?  For example, could you write a command line that would cause a music file to start playing?  The potential application would be that after a model is finished running, music would start to play, alerting you to the model's completion.

Comment: You could try if `alarm()` works for you.

Comment: What tune would you play to celebrate your program finishing?  The End by The Doors?  Probably not joyous enough.

Comment: I think that [this could be appropriate](http://youtu.be/oHg5SJYRHA0).

Comment: Ride of the Valkyries is always good for the first run of R in the morning.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpvLCptAHT8

Comment: This is a good question.  Sending an email or SMS to a cell phone is very useful when finishing a long job or when awaiting important results.

Comment: Ha!  You guys are the best!  I definitely like Ride of the Valkyries.  :)

Comment: It would be even better if you could play something sad when your program fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to `system`, on Windows at least you can use `shell.exec` which will open the file using the application specified in the Windows file associations. For example, `shell.exec("file.txt")` will open a text file in your favourite text editor, `shell.exec("file.mp3")` will launch a media player, etc.

Answer (score 7):

There is [audio package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/audio/) which allow to play wave files:

```
require(audio)
wave_file <- dir("C:/Windows/Media", pattern="\\.wav$", full.names=TRUE)[1] # some random windows wave file
f <- load.wave(wave_file)
play(f)
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but I'm having some trouble opening the .wav files.  I get this error message: Error in load.wave(wave_file) : unable to open file 'chimes.wav'

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by calling the [system()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.html) function.